# SQL Server last 25 records query optimization

Tags: sql-server

I have 4million records in one of my tables. I need to get the last 25 records that have been added in the last 1 week.

This is how my current query looks

```
SELECT TOP(25) [t].[EId],
               [t].[DateCreated],
               [t].[Message]
FROM   [dbo].[tblEvent] AS [t]
WHERE  ( [t].[DateCreated] >= Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getdate()) - 7, 0)
         AND [t].[EId] = 1 )
ORDER  BY [t].[DateCreated] DESC
```

Now I do not have any indexes running for this table and do not intend to have one. This query takes about 10-15 seconds to run and my apps times-out, now is there a way to better it?

Comment: Why don't you want an index on the table?

Comment: Well is a client driven call, and they don't want indexes, am not arguing with them more on this!

Comment: THen tell them to live with it or get a faster disc subsystem. Point. When clients aregue with reality, reality wins and does not care abuot clients delusions. There is not a lot of optimizations you can do on Sql level without getting rid of the IO of a table scan that you force.

Comment: @livingtolearn: well, that's just tough. You can't have "performance" and "no index" at the same time

Comment: Just to be clear does this table have any indexes at all (and if so what) or it is an unindexed heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an ID in the table that is autoincrement (not the Eid but a separate PK) you can order by ID desc instead of DateCreated, that might make your order by faster.

otherwise you do need an index (but your question says you do not want that).

Comment: It wont without index - still full table scans.

Comment: Well, you are right - I implicitly interpreted the question as "no additional indexes" to the clustered index on the PK

Answer (score 4):

You should create an index on `EId, DateCreated` or at least `DateCreated`

Without this only way of optimising this that I can think of would be to maintain the last 25 in a separate table via an `insert` trigger (and possibly `update` and `delete` triggers as well).

Answer (score 2):

If the table has no indexes to support the query you are going to be forced to perform a table scan.

You are going to struggle to get around the table scan aspect of that - and as the table grows, the response time will get slower.

You are going to have to endevour to educate your client as to the problems going forward they face, and that they should consider an index. They may be saying no, you need to show the evidence to support the reasoning, show them times with / without, and make sure the impact to the record insertion is also shown, it's a relatively simple cost / benefit / detriment for the adding of the index / not adding of it. If they insist on no index, then you have no choice but to extend your timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try query hint:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

With option `FAST n`  -- number of rows.

Comment: That isn't going to help. Without any indexes SQL Server will need to scan all 4 million rows to evaluate the `[EId] = 1` predicate and to do a `TOP N` sort.